# rendering svg vs image

Tags: html, css, image-processing, svg

I'm in a situation where I need to render a single image as  thumbnails multiple times in a list. I have the images as png and svg files, both with sizes smaller than 3kb

I would like to know if is it faster to render the images as png or as svg files. please mind the following assumptions:

- I'm planning to use the svgs as inline paths rendered from the server to avoid network latency
- In case I use the png files, they will only be loaded from network once and subsequent requests will hit the browser's cache .
- as stated before, the image needs to be loaded multiple times in a list like the following.

[image: list of vacancies]

Comment: [See this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SVG shouldn't really load any quicker or slower if the "filesize is the same" but remember older browsers may not support SVG natively but SVG can usually make advantage of gzip as they are XML files.

Sometimes simple SVG would likely be smaller than a bitmap file so would load quicker but that's purely to do with filesize not format.

Furthermore although good browsers support SVG usually they don't always support the full SVG specifications.